# CUDA my Tiled Matrix Multiplication using shared memory return 0 values at specific matrix size

Tags: matrix, cuda

I've tried to implement Big matrix multiplication using Shared Memory with Tiled Algorithm. And When I execute this code, I get correct results. 
But When I try to calculate more or equal than 4000 x 4000 sized matrix, It returns a matrix only filled with 0.

I couldn't find what's wrong with this code..

> the code below is Kernel function for matrix multiplication.

```
typedef float element;

#define TILE_WIDTH 32
#define WIDTH 4010
#define GRID_WIDTH ( (WIDTH) / TILE_WIDTH) + 1

__global__ void MatrixMulKernel(element* d_P, element* d_N, element* d_M, int Width) {
        __shared__ element ds_M[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
        __shared__ element ds_N[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];

        int bx = blockIdx.x; int by = blockIdx.y;
        int tx = threadIdx.x; int ty = threadIdx.y;

        int Row = by*TILE_WIDTH + ty;
        int Col = bx*TILE_WIDTH + tx;
        element pValue = 0;

        int length = (Width + TILE_WIDTH - 1)/TILE_WIDTH;
        for(int m = 0; m < length; m++) {
                if( m*TILE_WIDTH + tx < WIDTH && Row < WIDTH) ds_N[ty][tx] = d_N[Row*Width + m*TILE_WIDTH+tx];
                else ds_N[ty][tx] = 0.0;
                if( m*TILE_WIDTH + ty < WIDTH && Col < WIDTH) ds_M[ty][tx] = d_M[Col + (m*TILE_WIDTH+ty)*Width];
                else ds_M[ty][tx] = 0.0;

                __syncthreads();

                for(int k = 0; k < TILE_WIDTH; ++k) {
                        pValue += ds_N[ty][k]*ds_M[k][tx];
                }

                __syncthreads();
        }

        if( Row < Width && Col < Width)
                d_P[Row*Width+Col] = pValue;
}
```

> the code below is full code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

typedef float element;

#define TILE_WIDTH 32
#define WIDTH 4010
#define GRID_WIDTH ( (WIDTH) / TILE_WIDTH) + 1

__global__ void MatrixMulKernel(element* d_P, element* d_N, element* d_M, int Width) {
        __shared__ element ds_M[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
        __shared__ element ds_N[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];

        int bx = blockIdx.x; int by = blockIdx.y;
        int tx = threadIdx.x; int ty = threadIdx.y;

        int Row = by*TILE_WIDTH + ty;
        int Col = bx*TILE_WIDTH + tx;
        element pValue = 0;

        int length = (Width + TILE_WIDTH - 1)/TILE_WIDTH;
        for(int m = 0; m < length; m++) {
                if( m*TILE_WIDTH + tx < WIDTH && R

ow < WIDTH) ds_N[ty][tx] = d_N[Row*Width + m*TILE_WIDTH+tx];
                else ds_N[ty][tx] = 0.0;
                if( m*TILE_WIDTH + ty < WIDTH && Col < WIDTH) ds_M[ty][tx] = d_M[Col + (m*TILE_WIDTH+ty)*Width];
                else ds_M[ty][tx] = 0.0;

                __syncthreads();

                for(int k = 0; k < TILE_WIDTH; ++k) {
                        pValue += ds_N[ty][k]*ds_M[k][tx];
                }

                __syncthreads();
        }

        if( Row < Width && Col < Width)
                d_P[Row*Width+Col] = pValue;
}

void matmul(float* c, float* a, float* b, int width) {
        // c[y][x] = sum_k a[y][k] * b[k][x]
        // c[y * WIDTH + x] = sum_k a[y*WIDTH + k] * b[k*WIDTH + x]
        for (register int y = 0; y < width; ++y) {
                for (register int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                        register float sum = 0.0F;
                        for (register int k = 0; k < width; ++k) {
                                sum += a[y * width + k] * b[k * width + x];
                        }


     c[y * width + x] = sum;
                }
        }
}

void genData(element* ptr, unsigned int size) {
        while(size--) {
                ptr[size] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        }
}

int main() {
        element *pA = NULL;
        element *pB = NULL;
        element *pC = NULL;

        system_clock::time_point start;
        system_clock::time_point  end;

        srand(time(NULL));
        start = system_clock::now();

        // malloc meroies on the host-side
        pA = (element*)malloc(WIDTH * WIDTH  * sizeof(element));
        pB = (element*)malloc(WIDTH * WIDTH  * sizeof(element));
        pC = (element*)malloc(WIDTH * WIDTH  * sizeof(element));

        genData(pA, WIDTH*WIDTH);
        genData(pB, WIDTH*WIDTH);

//device side

        element *pAdev = NULL;
        element *pBdev = NULL;
        element *pCdev = NULL;

        cudaMalloc((void**)&pAdev, WIDTH*WIDTH*sizeof(element));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&pBdev, WIDTH*WIDTH*sizeof(element));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&pCdev, WIDTH*WIDTH*sizeof(element));

        cudaMemcpy(pAdev, pA, WIDTH * WIDTH * sizeof(element), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(pBdev, pB, WIDTH * WIDTH * sizeof(element), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        dim3 dimGrid(GRID_WIDTH, GRID_WIDTH, 1);
        dim3 dimBlock(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_WIDTH, 1);

        MatrixMulKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(pCdev, pAdev, pBdev, WIDTH);

        cudaMemcpy(pC, pCdev, WIDTH * WIDTH * sizeof(element), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


        element *test;
        test = (element*)malloc(WIDTH * WIDTH * sizeof(element));


     matmul(test, pA, pB, WIDTH);
        bool flag = true;
        for(int i = 0; i<WIDTH; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j<WIDTH; j++) {
                        if(pC[i*WIDTH+j] != test[i*WIDTH+j]) {
                                printf("%f, %f\n", pC[i*WIDTH+j], test[i*WIDTH+j]);
                                flag = false;
                        }
                 }
        }

        if(flag) printf("TRUE\n");
        else printf("FALSE\n");

        end = system_clock::now();

        cout << "Elapsed time : " << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start).count() << "ns" << '\n';

        free(pA);
        free(pB);
        free(pC);
        cudaFree(pAdev);
        cudaFree(pBdev);
        cudaFree(pCdev);

        return 0;
}
```

I am waiting for your answer! Thank you!

Comment: Look at the size of the matrices you are passing in, the dimension of your grid, and how they match (or not). Then decide on what those threads should do that have no corresponding matrix element. Always check return codes from CUDA calls for errors. Run your code under cuda-memcheck to detect stray memory accesses. Apologies for not giving a full answer but I've become tired of repeatedly answering the same questions.

Comment: if you are running your code on a display device, you are probably hitting a display driver watchdog timer limit.

Comment: @tera I think It is not the duplicate of the question? I've already saw the question. and I already referred to the question to implement the code for non-multiple WIDTH matrix. and The point of question is more than specific WIDTH this code code gives me trash values. Thank you. and I will try to check errors

Comment: When I run your code as-is on CUDA 8, I get the output: `TRUE
Elapsed time : 475869653010ns`.   So I think the problem is probably what @talonmies said: a display watchdog timeout.  If you're on windows, search on "WDDM TDR".  If you're on linux, read [this](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).  But regardless, you should always use [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) when you're having trouble with a CUDA code.

Comment: Yeah I solved it Thank you.. @RobertCrovella